# Sorting columns in table displaying weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting

I am pulling some data from a webservice and filling a table. I wanted the columns to be able to sort the data in ascending and descending order based on the user clicking an arrow. It used to work fine, but I recently added a some other js and now the sort *"works"*. Should there just not be one definite order for ascending and one definite order for descending? Currently when I click on a column it appears that that column is sorting in ascending and descending order, but if you watch the columns to the right of it, it seems like they are going through some sort of loop.

You would expect clicking one column 2 times all data would be back to where it was 2 click ago, but it takes like 26-28 clicks to get all of the other columns exactly back where they were. Is this normal behavior, because most of the entries have the same value in certain columns? It appears like it might be cycling through all things that have the same name before the one with the same exact values appears back at the top of the ascending list.

I have a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZAmdeP4vjoZd1QN1nGY?p=preview) displaying the behavior I am talking about. Just sort by name and watch the columns on the right side.

This is how I am calling the `ng-repeat` for the table:

```
    <tr data-ng-repeat="alert in recentalerts | orderBy:savedOrder:reverse">
      <td>{{alert.name}}</td>
      <td>{{alert.time}}</td>
      <td>{{alert.ip}}</td>
      <td>{{alert.column}}</td>
      <td>{{alert.type}}</td>
    </tr>
```

where `savedOrder` is just the last thing the user chose to sort by. It's used to keep track of the sorting order in between `$interval`'s.

Comment: Depending on the algorithm used, the order for the lines that have a common column value is probably not guaranteed. {from erp: **You would expect clicking one column 2 times all data would be back to where it was 2 click ago**} A correct sort algorithm usually only guarantee that the data is sorted in ascending order or descending order.

Comment: Also for the sorting order to be reversible to its previous order, you would need to keep an unsorted list of your values in memory somewhere (not the table values but a copy of them), sort a copy of the unordered list then adjust the lines according to that sorted list.  This guarantees the same order.